# FPGA-insert error in data package

Tags: tcp, verilog, fpga

How can insert an error in data package? I'd like to insert errors in a packet data, which has the structure of a TCP IP. Has someone ever worked in Verilog on this thing and can help me out?

Comment: what do you define as error? can you give some examples of the type of error you are talking about?

Comment: Do you need fault injection in simulation or after synthesis on a device? Should the FPGA insert the errors itself or are they software inserted by a PC? Should the fault injection be configurable or programmable? To your question: Yes many people have worked on such 'feature'...

Comment: error insert reversing the least significant bit of the word. I still try to Verilog description of a programmable module insertion of errors into data pack,for example tcp packet,but error will be introduced in Data Tcp.

Answer (score 0):

Define how much your error rate will be. That is, how much time will happen between two errors. Let's say it's 1 error for every N bits transmitted. For simplicity, make N to be a power of 2.

Design a random number generator that can generate pseudorandom number between 0 and 2*N-1 and use it to initialize a bit counter. If this is for simulation, you can just use the `$random` system function.

For every bit transmited, decrease the counter. When it reachs 0, toogle the next bit to be transmited to cause the packet in which it is to have an error, and set the counter again to another random value.